# Check apply condition only if non None in Python

Tags: python, nonetype, or-operator

I want date either be condition or be `None` and make condition true. So I wrote

```
if (self.StartDate is None) or (d >= self.StartDate):
```

But PyCharm checker swears:

> Expected type 'date', got 'None' instead

Why and how to succeed?

**UPDATE**

`d` is date of current enumerated item; if `self.StartDate` is `None`, then all `d`-s should processed, and if `self.StartDate` contains date, it should cut all earlier `d`-s

Comment: the *why to succeed* is a very good question. Its a pity that only the *how* will be answered

Comment: What, or which type is your self.StarDate of?

Comment: What is `d` here?

Comment: why do you care about what pycharm have to complain about? you know that if the first condition in the if statement is true so it doesn't matter if the Startdate is None, python interpreter will not check it

Comment: @Koanashi sometimes it is date and then it should play, other times it is None, then it should not play

Comment: @MartijnPieters `d` is date of current enumerated item; if `self.StartDate` is `None`, then all `d`-s should processed, and if `self.StartDate` contains date, it should cut all earlier `d`-s

Comment: @LichKing I am not so fluent to Python, so care about anything :D

Comment: Probably an error in PyCharm. Lose the parentheses.